# Datattables Laravel 5.4 - FatalThrowableError Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Datatables()

Tags: laravel, datatables

I'm using datatables with laravel 5.4, but when I use the datatables()->query():

in providers: Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,

in aliases: 'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables::class,

My code:

```
return Datatables()->query( /**query**/ )
```

return this error in my console:

> FatalThrowableError
>
> App\Http\Controllers\Datatables()

I've tried datatables() and Datatables()

Someone with the same problem?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, simply paste it here. See this post on how to format code on StackOverflow if you need more info. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Sorry, updated!

Comment: @RafaelNovoletto it is it is `return datatables()->query` as per the [documentation](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables#jquery-datatables-api-for-laravel-45)

Comment: @HamzaMohamed i'm try Datatables() and datatables()
in localhost Datatables() works.. and in the host, don't work.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because Laravel cannot find your package Datatables.

Laravel in controllers, if you are not mapping your classes correctly will always seek the called classes at this point `App\Http\Controllers`.

Just put `use DataTables;` or `use \Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;` at the start of your controller and it shall be fixed. [documentation](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter#create-controller)

When you install any package through composer, composer uses namespace to find the package and route functions and classes to it.

you can read more about the namespaces from [php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

and you can check this tutorial for [namespaces](https://jtreminio.com/2012/10/composer-namespaces-in-5-minutes/).

Also, Laravel follows the PSR 4 when it comes to autoloading, you can check it from [here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: use \Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use Datatables;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables; <- Its work in localhost

Comment: can you check if you have installed the package on your host as well?

Comment: @RafaelNovoletto in the terminal of your host .. specifically in your laravel folder .. type `composer info` .. Yajra should appear below .. if not then it is not installed.

Comment: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle       v7.0.0  jQuery DataTables API for Laravel 4|5

Comment: there should be more than 1 package for Yajra .. also, try to apply these commands to clear the cached files `php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`
and finally `composer dump-autoload` then check again

Comment: Solved!
I'm run:
Step 1: composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^8.0 
Setp 2: artisan vendor:publish --provider=Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider 
Step 3: php artisan cache:clear
Step 4: php artisan config:cache

Comment: great .. that means that you didnt have Yajra package installed at the first place .. for future .. make sure when you upload your files .. you run `composer install` so all the vendor files can be available for you.